# Jquery tool tip is not showing with AJAX data load

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, tooltip, jquery-ui-tooltip

I am having issue regarding the showing tooltip on the ajax loaded content, I am adding the tooltip to ul with a function, and trying to bind it with mouse over event as it works.

```
str += '<li><a href="#" class="tooltip-1" data-placement="top" data-original-title="' + _icon_list[2] + ':' + obj[_icon_list[1]] + '">' +
            '<i class="' + _icon_list[0] + '"></i></a></li>';
```

after adding the data I am trying to bind it

```
$('a.tooltip-1').on({
                "mouseover": function() {
                    tool_tip();
                },
                "mouseout": function() {
                    $(this).tooltip("disable");
                }
            });



function tool_tip() {
    $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip()
}
```

it's getting callback but not showing the tooltip? here is the link of theme which has the tooltip and i am using it with my dynamic content.

http://www.soaptheme.net/wordpress/citytours/shortcodes/

Answer (score 0):

Where is your ajax function?
Just add a `title="your tooltip text here`" in your href and in you ajax callback call this command.

```
$('a.tooltip-1').tooltip( );
```

Comment: I am getting the callback but the tooltip is not showing :( I saw the theme page but couldn't understand how it's adding it or how can i bind it dynamic because there is no data-toggle attribute in it.

Comment: where is the element having attribute data-toggle="tooltip"? Can you show your html?

Comment: I changed the code so `.tooltip()` is executed on the same element beign hovered.I guess that is you really want and you dont need the tool_tip() function you have?Can you give more information on what exactly you want?

Comment: I have tried it but it's still not showing the tooltip on mouse hover, if you look here http://www.soaptheme.net/wordpress/citytours/shortcodes the tooltip-1 is coming on normal but not with the dynamic content as I am using the same theme.